# Who is this shadow from the second Valvrave ED?

Tags: valvrave-the-liberator

The second ending theme of Valvrave the Liberator ends with this screenshot. The girl on the left is mysterious, but we have at least some idea of who she is given that she seems to be related to the control system for Valvrave I. However, the shadowy figure behind her doesn't match her body, so it's likely a different character.

Who (or what) is that shadow?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This character is revealed at the end of episode 12.

> Cain entered the cockpit of the Valvrave Two (which didn't start up until this episode) with an orb that he referred to as ***Prue***.
>
>  [image: 21:00]
>
>  The helix in the orb reacted, and at the same time, the display in the cockpit of Valvrave Two showed an image of a man, which matches the shadow in the question.
>
>  [image: 21:08]
>
>  The girl in Valvrave One refers to him as ***Onii-chan***.